# Json response to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, httpresponse

I have an API response in text as below:

`'[[["gam ind us tries","house"],["1530","house_number"],["jamacha rd ste","road"],["pel cajon","city"],["ca","state"],["92019","postcode"],["us","country"]]]\n'`

As yoou all can see, the reponse is in key value pairs. I wanted to put this data into dataframe as below:

[image: Its the expected output]

I tried it by normalizing the json response but however the input is not exactly key value pairs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify is response JSON or TEXT and is this example all - Providing some more code / details would be great. Thanks

Comment: its text sir, however you can use response.json() as well

Comment: Do you only have one text or many of them?

Comment: [[['gam ind us tries', 'house'],
  ['1530', 'house_number'],
  ['jamacha rd ste', 'road'],
  ['pel cajon', 'city'],
  ['ca', 'state'],
  ['92019', 'postcode'],
  ['us', 'country']]]

Comment: only one text @onyambu

Comment: @onyambu the above response is in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = '[[["gam ind us tries","house"],["1530","house_number"],["jamacha rd ste","road"],["pel cajon","city"],["ca","state"],["92019","postcode"],["us","country"]]]\n'

pd.DataFrame(eval(a)[0]).set_index(1).T

              house house_number            road  ... state postcode country
0  gam ind us tries         1530  jamacha rd ste  ...    ca    92019      us

[1 rows x 7 columns]
```

or even:

```
pd.DataFrame({key:val for val, key in eval(a)[0]}, index = [0])

              house house_number            road  ... state postcode country
0  gam ind us tries         1530  jamacha rd ste  ...    ca    92019      us

[1 rows x 7 columns]
```